# is it safe to create a new thread inside actionPerformed in swing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I created swing application that do some operations in performedAction methode, but when i create a thread that shows the progressBar, the progressBar will not visible during the performedAction methode, but at the end the progressBar will be visible with a value of 100% directly
**main class:**

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame win = new JFrame("Test");
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        Button b1 = new Button("Click ");
        win.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                window win = new window();
                win.start();
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e5){}
            }
        });
        win.setLayout(layout);
        win.setSize(500, 300);
        win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**window class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class window extends Thread{
    public window(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame fen = new JFrame("New window");
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        fen.setLayout(layout);
        Button b2 = new Button();
        fen.setVisible(true);
        fen.setSize(100, 100);
        fen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fen.add(b2);
        try
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                b2.setLabel("Button " + i);
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e2){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing it all wrong. Read the swing concurrency tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/. And please, respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe to create a new `Thread` inside of an `actionPerformed` handler.

**But, no thread other than the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT) must interact with the Swing components.**

To create animations, or delays inside of Swing, you must use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).  Executing a `Thread.sleep()` on the EDT is never allowed, and won't do want you hope it will.

To return from a spawned thread to the EDT, you must use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) or [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-).

Using a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is the preferred way to execute background tasks in Swing.  It handles communication and publication of partial and final results from the background task to the EDT for displaying in the GUI components.

---

The following is a translation of your code to a working example, using a `SwingWorker`.  Instead of AWT `Button`'s, the Swing `JButton` is used.  The program is created using `invokeAndWait` to ensure the main window construction occurs on the EDT.  A lambda function is used, but you can replace this with `new Runnable() { }` inner class, if desired.  The "Button 0" through "Button 100" progress reports are published from the `SwingWorker` background task, for processing in the EDT.  Multiple results can be generated at by the background thread before the EDT has a chance to process them; here, we take only the last result to display in the button.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            JFrame win = new JFrame("Test");
            win.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            JButton b1 = new JButton("Click");
            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    DoWork work = new DoWork();
                    work.execute();
                }
            });
            win.add(b1);
            win.setSize(500, 300);
            win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            win.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

class DoWork extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    JFrame fen;
    JButton b2;

    DoWork() {
        fen = new JFrame("New window");
        fen.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b2 = new JButton();
        fen.add(b2);
        fen.setSize(100, 100);
        fen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fen.setVisible(true);
        fen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            publish("Button " + i);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> data) {
        String last = data.get(data.size() - 1);
        b2.setText(last);
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        fen.dispose();
    }
}
```

There are still a number of improvements that can be made to this code.  A `JLabel` instead of a `JButton` for displaying the results, a `JDialog` for the progress window, or perhaps better a `ProgressMonitor`.  These are left as an exercise to the student.